# How to run batches NOT using cmd.exe (like Cmder.exe?)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cmder

I've recently installed [cmder](https://cmder.net/) (or simply 'Commander') portable console emulator for windows, and really like the functionalities it comes with. But how can you (if at all) run batches through it like you can with the Windows command line?

**The details:**

If you write...

```
cd C:\test\
REM executeSomething.exe
Pause
```

... to a textfile and save it as a `.bat` file you can do can do pretty much anything just by double-clicking that file. I've got a work-flow where I launch a web-application through a batch file. Sometimes this applicaton launches automatically in Chrome, [and sometimes it does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363942/starting-jupyter-from-batch-will-not-open-web-browser). In that case, I'll have to copy and paste a URL to Chrome manually. And that's a real pain. With `cmder.exe` that's much easier, but I'll have to manually navigate to a folder and start the application through Commander it manually without the luxury of a `.bat file`.

The functionality I'm trying to run automatically with cmder.exe is simply changing a folder and starting an executable file, specifically `Jupyter Lab`:

```
cd C:\jupyterlab\
jupyter lab
Pause
```

I've tried various approaches with:

```
@echo off
set CMDER_ROOT=C:\Cmder
start %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe" /title "Homestead VM" /loadcfgfile "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\ConEmu.xml" /cmd cmd /k "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat cd %CD% && %~1"
```

as described [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/457), but with no success. The example above *does* launch commander, but also raises a syntax error:

> Current directory: C:\batches
>
> Command to be executed: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"  /k
>   "C:\Cmder\vendor\init.bat cd C:\batches && "

I'm obviously on to somehting here since I'm able to start Commander, but I'm not sure how to edit the remaining code to run the necessary steps. I do realize that the `/title "Homestead VM"` part just edits the title of the Commander window:

[image]

but I have no idea about the rest.

If this just isn't possible, I'm going to have to try to reassociate `.bat` files in `Control Panel > Default Programs > Associate a filetype`, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**System info:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit
Commander v1.3.12
```

---

**Edit 1:** My (failed) attempt trying to follow a suggestion from Gerhard Barnard

---

I've saved a file named `please.cmd` to `C:\Windows\System32` that contains this:

```
@echo off
if not defined CMDER_ROOT set "CMDER_ROOT=C:\Cmder"
start %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe" /title "Homestead VM" /loadcfgfile "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\ConEmu.xml" /cmd cmd /k "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat cd %CD% && %~1"
```

I've also saved a file named `SObatch.bat` in `C:\batches` that contains this:

```
if not defined myComs set myComs=0 && please %~0
@echo off
ping localhost
echo %userprofile%
pause
```

Upon double-clicking `SObatch.bat` a Windows prompt is opened, and the pings are run:

[image]

I just narrowed the window to leave out real-world user-names. But the ping functions are being run and the usual responses are returned.

So I guess it still seems that I've broken something.

Comment: What is the reason you set `CMDER_ROOT` in the script, it should be pre-defined.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed cmder to test and it launches batch files just fine. You broke yours. :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks for responding. I set `CMDER_ROOT` to `C:Cmder` because I was also trying `CMDER_ROOT=%~dp0` but that raised other issues. I see from another comment that this worked for you. Would you consider taking the time to write up the specifics in an answer? I've failed to specify my system. I'll add that in the question.

Comment: Ok, so just to be sure, is the purpose of this to double click the batch file and then let it start up in `cmder` instead of `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, exactly!

Comment: ok, so that would need you to make changes in all your batch files in order to launch them in cmder instead.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I'm totally fine with that as long I only have to change the ones I'd like to run. Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: What happens when you open `cmd` and just run `please "echo Hello world"`

Comment: Please see the changes in my answer for batch file. Can you please try it as is. (also assuming you named the file `please.bat`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Replaced `please.bat` with `please.cmd` in `C:\Windows\System32`, but it's still `cmd.exe` that is being launched...

Comment: ok, but you still need to make the new changes to the script as I mentioned below in the edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `please.cmd` and save it to `C:\Windows\System32` as administrator. It should then exist as `c:\Windows\System32\please.cmd`

```
@echo off
if not defined CMDER_ROOT set "CMDER_ROOT=C:\Cmder"
start %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe" /title "Homestead VM" /loadcfgfile "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\ConEmu.xml" /cmd cmd /k "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat cd %CD% && %*"
```

Now when you create a batch files you need to make some changes in the top of each batch file you want. You would need to add the below line to the very top of the script.

```
"%systemroot%\system32\please.cmd" "%~f0" && goto :eof
```

You can also from cmd `please command` to launch it from the `cmder` shell. Example:

```
please ping localhost
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I'm understanding you correctly I need to (1) store the first snippet in `C:\Windows\System32` and leave it like that. And then (2) to run a batch through cmrd I need a file double click a file that contains snippet. But when I do, the batch is run in the windows cmd.exe, and not cmdr.exe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you change the first line to reflect my line in the batch file? `if not defined myComs set myComs=0 && please %~0`

Comment: I'll make an edit to the question to show exactly what I tried.

Comment: better use `"%~f0"` instead of `%~0`. Maybe even `&& "%systemroot%\system32\please.cmd" "%~f0"`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan I was placing it in system32 hoping that it would work through path, but yes, I think it is safer to call full path. Let me update.

Comment: I updated the answer to exit the initial batch file as well as it would still have continued running in cmd after calling the batch in cmder.

Comment: Please see the amended answer. I made some changes so you would need to replicate everything.